# How do I access xmm registers in an eBPF program

Tags: x86-64, trace, bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I am trying to use bcc-tools to trace a user process using uprobe, but some functions take floating point arguments. According to x86_64 ABI, these values are normally passed in the xmm registers.

The eBPF functions in bcc takes a `struct pt_regs *` argument and in that I can get access to (a copy of ?) most "usual" registers, but not the xmm registers.

Is there a way to accomplish this ? Or is this something that was overlooked in the design of eBPF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** This is not an issue with BPF, neither uprobes nor kprobes can access AVX registers such as xmm registers.

---

uprobe programs are actually [loaded in the kernel as kprobe programs](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/2ddbc07782c3ca4115a0840882e42dfb0c88686d/src/python/bcc/__init__.py#L988) (i.e., `BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE`).

Contrary to most BPF programs, kprobe programs have access to an unmodified, unrestricted context argument at the hook point. What I mean is that the argument of BPF programs is often a mirror of the actual object given at the hook point, with accesses rewritten by the verifier. For example, several BPF programs take `struct __sk_buff` as argument, which is actually [a mirror of `sk_buff`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.7/source/net/core/filter.c#L3896) (see [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051729/bpf-translation-of-program-contexts/49128551#49128551) for more details). kprobe program, on the contrary, have access to the raw `struct pt_regs` object (the `convert_ctx_access` field of [`struct bpf_verifier_ops`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.7/source/include/linux/bpf.h#L179) is [null](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.7/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L584)).

From this we can conclude that kprobes (which receive `struct pt_regs`) don't have access to the AVX registers. So it's a limitation of kprobes and not of BPF. One reason for this might simply be the low support for AVX registers in the kernel. Please see [this StackOverflow answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475956/why-can-the-kernel-not-use-sse-avx-registers-and-instructions) for further information.

Comment: Thanks @pchaigno for an elaborate answer.  However, wouldn't it be possible to enable *read* access to any processor register in eBPF (e.g. by number), without violating security or portability ? I am not suggesting a design change for eBPF, just curious.

Comment: Just read the refered SO answer on low support for AVX registers in the kernel.  What I am looking for is probably not eBPF, but a pure userlevel framework to instrument code.  Again, thanks @pchaigno for clearing this out to me!

Comment: Kprobe BPF programs require root access so it's probably more of an issue of performance than an issue of security (or portability). I'm not familiar enough on these registers though, so don't take my work for it.

Comment: Please prefer accepting the answer to up voting if it answers your question. It helps people and SO identify and reference the answer.